# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Asp.net MVC (Edit Page)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I just want to make CRUD Operation with Image and also with other  Student information. I just get that when i open the Edit page.

**The code of Edit View:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">ÖĞRENCİ DÜZENLEME SAYFASI</h1>
            <p class="lead">Bu ekrandan öğrenci bilgilerini düzenleyebilirsiniz.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btn btn-light">
        @Html.ActionLink("  Öğrenci Listesine Geri Dön", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning fa fa-list" })
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <hr />
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>ALAN</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Alanını Giriniz. Örneğin; Sayısal, Sözel</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>SINIF</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
                    @Html.DropDownList("Class_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Sınıfını Seçiniz</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Class_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>GRUP</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i></span>
                    @Html.DropDownList("Group_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci hazırlandığı sınav türünü seçiniz</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Group_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>TC NUMARASI</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TCno, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci TC Kimlik numarası giriniz</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TCno, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>AD</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-font"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Ad</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <label>SOYAD</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-strikethrough"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Soyadı Giriniz</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>CİNSİYET</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-intersex"></i></span>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, true) <strong>Bay</strong></td>
                            <td> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
                            <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, false) <strong>Bayan</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Cinsiyeti seçiniz</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>DOĞUM TARİHİ</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Doğum Tarihi</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>ÖĞRENCİ TELEFON</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Mobil telefon numarası giriniz. Ör: 05xx xxx xxxx</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>DURUM</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i></span>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Status, true) <strong>Aktif</strong></td>
                            <td> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
                            <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Status, false) <strong>Pasif</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Durumunu seçiniz</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>FOTOĞRAF</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <img src="@Url.Content(Session["Image"].ToString())" height="100" width="100" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" value="Dosya Seç..." name="ImageFile">
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci fotoğrafı seçiniz. 1 MB küçük |.png|.jpg|.jpeg uzantılı dosyayı seçiniz.</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1"></div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>E-POSTA</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eMail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Sisteme giriş yapabilmesi için bir E-Posta adresi giriniz.</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eMail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>ŞİFRE</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Sisteme giriş yapabilmesi için bir şifre giriniz.</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label>KATILMA TARİHİ</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfJoin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Katılma tarihini giriniz.</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfJoin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>AYRILMA TARİHİ</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfLeave, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Ayrılma tarihini seçiniz.</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>ADRES</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: 100px" })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci Adres'ini giriniz.</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>VELİ AD</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-id-badge"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci'nin Veli adını giriniz.</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>VELİ TELEFON 1</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentPhone1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci'nin Veli Telefon numarasını giriniz.</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentPhone1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>VELİ TELEFON 2</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentPhone2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci'nin Veli yedek telefon numarasını giriniz.</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>VELİ CİNSİYET</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-intersex"></i></span>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ParentGender, true) <strong>Bay</strong></td>
                            <td> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
                            <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ParentGender, false) <strong>Bayan</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Veli'nin cinsiyetini seçiniz.</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentGender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>AÇIKLAMA</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: 100px" })
                </div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Öğrenci için bir açıklama giriniz.</small>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ">
                    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o">&nbsp; &nbsp;Değişiklikleri Kaydet</i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    }
</div>
```

**The code of Student Controller:**

```
private DBClassroomEntities db = new DBClassroomEntities();
/ GET: Student/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var student = db.Students.Find(id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.Class_Id = new SelectList(db.Classes, "ID", "Name", student.Class_Id);
        ViewBag.Group_Id = new SelectList(db.Groups, "ID", "Name", student.Group_Id);
        return View(student);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Student student)
    { //does not enter here because I can't see the old data in Student.
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.Class_Id = new SelectList(db.Classes, "ID", "Name", student.Class_Id);
        ViewBag.Group_Id = new SelectList(db.Groups, "ID", "Name", student.Group_Id);
        return View(student);
    }
```

**The code of  Student Model**

```
public partial class Student
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Student()
    {
        this.Discontinuities = new HashSet<Discontinuity>();
        this.Grades = new HashSet<Grade>();
        this.Payments = new HashSet<Payment>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Class_Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Group_Id { get; set; }
    public string TCno { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string eMail { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfJoin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfLeave { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public string ParentPhone1 { get; set; }
    public string ParentPhone2 { get; set; }
    public bool ParentGender { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //public HttpPostedFileBase filex { get; set; }

    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Discontinuity> Discontinuities { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

**and the Error:**

[Screenshot of error (When I click the Edit page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxPvg.png)

So, i am dealing with this error for a week. Sorry for long code.

Note: if I delete the div which has in line 180, get error elsewhere

Thanks for any help.

**Update:**
It's Work by default view

```
<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Student</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Class_Id, "Class_Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Class_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Class_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Group_Id, "Group_Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Group_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Group_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TCno, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TCno, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TCno, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birthday, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eMail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eMail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eMail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfJoin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfJoin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfJoin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfLeave, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfLeave, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfLeave, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentPhone1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentPhone1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentPhone1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentPhone2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentPhone2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentPhone2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentGender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentGender)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentGender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Photo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The message object reference not set show at that line of code but the real error may come from another line.

Please check all null case in model object. You can add `@if (Model != null){ }` 
wrap to line 180

Also change source for dropdown from

```
@Html.DropDownList("Class_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownList("Class_Id", (SelectList)ViewBag.Class_Id , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Not working. I shared the default code. It's work. But my code which with bootstrap dosent work. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I found the proble. I check all null case in model.

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Session["Image"].ToString())" height="100" width="100" />
```

This session gives an error because nothing is assigned. It's make me dizy, bec showing the error elsewhere.

```
Session["Image"] it's null
```

Thanks again :)